# Is there a mathematical proof that says an integer 'n' can have atmost root(n) factors. Is this statement even true?

Tags: c++, math, time-complexity

Suppose if I have to perform an operation on every factor of n that takes O(n). Will its time complexity be O(n * sqrt(n)) or O(n * n) if I write the following program in C++.

```
for(int i=1;i<n;++i){
  if(n%i==0){
     Some operation of O(n);
  }
}
```

I know there does exist a far more efficient solution but the reason I am asking this question is because I submitted this code in a contest with constraints on n<=10^5 and it got accepted. Thanks already.

Comment: @two.X sir your asymptotic notation is quite confusing. Don't you want to say O(n * sqrt(n) ).

Comment: Hint: for each factor `r` there is another one, `n / r`.

Comment: seems more like a question for [math.se]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699330/upper-bound-on-number-of-factors

Comment: if `n<100000` I guess maybe `O(n^2)` or `O(n^3)` would still pass.

Comment: If you can find two factors larger than sqrt(n) we have a problem.

Comment: @BoP Why? `6`, `8` and `12` are all factors of `n = 24`, and they're all larger than `sqrt(24)`.

Comment: If n <= 10^5 then `O(n) == O(10^5) == O(1)`. `O` notation and constraints do not mix. You have to look at `O` notation always without no constraints.

Comment: Shouldn't that code use `i <= n`? n is a factor of n just like 1.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking about the asymptotic growth behavior of the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function).

Basically you can see that this code is O(n * sqrt(n)) by rewriting it as follows:

```
void do_linear_time_task(int divisor, int n) {
    // do something that takes O(n) time...
}

void takes_sqrt_n_times_n_time(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= static_cast<int>(std::sqrt(n)); ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {

            int divisor_1 = i;
            int divisor_2 = n / i;

            if (divisor_1 == divisor_2) {
                // they are the same number so just call the O(n) routine once.
                do_linear_time_task(divisor_1, n);
            } else {
                do_linear_time_task(divisor_1, n);
                do_linear_time_task(divisor_2, n);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The above will call the O(n) routine on the same numbers as the original code but in this version it is pretty clear it can't do that more than O(sqrt(n)) times.